# Is it possible to construct such a symmetric matrix with desired eigenvalues?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, dense-matrix

Suppose a real, dense and asymmetric square matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,
all its eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in \mathbb R$

Is it possible to construct a symmetric matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, the eigenvalues of which are $\lambda_i^2$ to compute absolute values of $\lambda_i$ without the need of solving eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I don't understand what you want the relationship between $A$ and $B$ to be?

Comment: Originally, I would expect $B=A^TA$, but it is not the case unless $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for $A^2$?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are asking for a *symmetric* matrix. So we can restate your question as how to construct a symmetric matrix $B$ with the same eigenvalues of $A^2$, without first computing the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. Is your goal to *construct a matrix* $B$ so that its eigenvalues are $\lambda^2_i$? Such a matrix is, for example, given by $B=L A L^T$ where $A=LL^T$ is a triangular decomposition. But then what? Is your goal to find an easier way to get at the eigenvalues of $A$ by finding the eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth, yes that is what I mean. But the original $A$ has the form: $A_{100\times 100}=J^TG_{3\times 3}J_{3\times 100}$

Comment: The real problem is, I have got a symmetric matrix $A_{1000\times 1000}=J^TG_{3\times 3}J_{3\times 1000}$; its nonzero eigenvalues are also eigenvalues of $B_{3\times 3}=JJ^TG$, where $B$ is asymmetric; and the eigenvlaues of $B$ can be obtained by Schur factorization. I am seeking for further simplification possibilities when only the square of nonzero eigenvalues needed;

Comment: But $B_{3\times 3}$ is only of size 3, right? You can basically write down the eigenvalues of this matrix. The entire cost is going to be to form the product $JJ^T$ which is still far cheaper than computing the eigenvalues of $A$. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to calculate both Schur factorization of $B$ and eigenvalues of $A$. They are efficient and acceptable.